# Implementing a horizontal compass on the iPhone - algorithm?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A horizontal compass looks something like this if you are facing due East (90 degrees).

```
85----90---95
```

If you were facing due 355 degrees northwest, it would look like this:

```
350----355---0
```

As you turn the compass, the number should cycle from 0 -> 360 -> 0

So, my question is, how would you implement a view like this on the iPhone? I had a couple of ideas:

1. Make one long image with all numbers
   and tick marks, and shift it
   left/right when the compass heading
   changes
2. Create pieces of the view as tiles
   and append them when the compass
   heading changes.
3. Create a line of tick marks that
   shifts with the compass heading, and
   just write numbers on it as needed.

How would you attack this problem? Im mainly looking for algorithmic advice, but if you ave code or pseudo-code to demonstrate, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one is the easiest.  Keep in mind that you can composite part of an image to deal with the wrap-around.

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it. It wasn't too hard.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that images with text don't scale well, particularly when upsampled to higher-resolution devices.  You also have the overhead of tagging along some number of resolution-specific image files which bloats your binary.  You can implement a custom view and do your drawing in `drawRect:` very easily and it doesn't suffer from either of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution of implementing horizontal compass in iPhone 4

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) 
    {
        m_locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        m_locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        m_locationManager.headingOrientation=CLDeviceOrientationPortrait;;
        m_locationManager.delegate=self;
        [m_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

    }
```

## pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    CLLocationDirection direction= newHeading.magneticHeading;
    [m_readingsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Degrees:%f",direction]];

    float radians=direction*M_PI/180;
    m_compassImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the modulo 10 of the heading and switch for 10, 5 and all others.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to implement location manager functionality to find the exact direction in which your iPhone is pointing.

So, You can check this :

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

And whenever you call startUpdatingHeading() it will call 
"`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading`" method which you need to override from Location manager.

And that's it you can find the direction in which iPhone 3GS is pointing by newHeading.magneticHeading or newHeading.trueHeading.

You will surprise that you can get exact the same direction what magnetic compass gives you.